# window.location not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, blackberry, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi all I am navigating from one html page to another as:

```
window.location = "test.html";
```

In test.html I have header as:

```
<script type="application/javascript">

            function redirect()
            {
                alert("inside redirect:");
                //window.location = url;
                //history.back();
                history.go(-1);
                return false;

            }

        </script>

        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>

                <li> <a href="#" data-theme="b" onclick="history.back(); return false;">Go Back</a></li>
                <li> <a onclick="redirect()" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-left jqm-home">Back1</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

But here both back buttons (Go Back and Back1) are not working. If I use `$.mobile.changePage('test.html')` to navigate between pages then both Back buttons work. Why they are not with windows.location?

I want to develop this application for B-Grade browser which are not support ajax. Therefore I cant use `$.mobile.changePage('test.html')`.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which Mobile and OS you are particularly targetting? Blackberry OS 5?

Comment: Yes. If I use window.location.assign("first.html"); then it navigate from test.html to first.html but when I press back button of mobile (hardware button ) then it again navigate to test.html

Comment: Whats the issue in `$.mobile.changePage('test.html')` It works very fine in that...

Comment: No $.mobile.changePage('test.html') does not run in blackberry5.

Comment: I have written an entire application for BB OS 5 using `changePage` thousand times... You just need to disable ajax thats all.....

Comment: @Coder_sLaY  Thanks for reply But are you sure if you have two different html files one.html and two.html on calling  $.mobile.changePage('two.html')  from one.html it navigate to two.html?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14447/discussion-between-coder-slay-and-ppd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **Blackberry OS 5** browser has lots of issue. Initially i also tried to do what you are doing right now. But later i think so you will have to think of some other approach which is better. Here is how i solved it

First of all add these lines before loading the jquery-mobile script like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    });
</script>
```

Then i used the **Single Html concept**. In this concept i had to load my  script just once and i could make use of jquery-mobile's `changePage`. When i had many html pages then i has to wait for some seconds as loading and unloading of scripts took place. Avoid that, Its unnecessarry.

Have all the pages with in the same Html like this

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
.
.
.
```

Then after that you can easily do a `changePage` like this

```
$.mobile.changePage("#page1", {
    transition : "slide"
});
```

I hope you take the right approach.

Comment: I tried it with BB5. Ihave three html files 1,2,3.html. In each file there is single button and onclick of button I call $.mobile.changePage('2.html'). But when I go from 1 to 2.html it shows one progress bar (ehich is not added by me) and 2.html is not display,here it shows still one.html with progress bar. In second scenario I have only 1.html and 2.html here on click button of one.html it display 2.html but here also it shows progress bar. And same code runs perfect on BB6 with both cases.

Comment: But I have many html files is it good to put all pages in single html file?

Comment: Do you have the phonegap and jquery mobile scripts in the header of all the HTML files you have?

Comment: yes I Have phonegap and jquery mobile scripts in the header of all the HTML files. And I have near about 50 html files.

Comment: See whenever you call a new html page then the old scripts which got loaded gets unloaded and again the new scripts in the second HTML gets loaded. This takes up memory and time. This is inefficient when it comes to mobile. Thats why i preferred you to have a single HTML file so that you have to load the script only once...

Comment: @Coder-sLay thanks for suggestions and time.  It means in my application I will have a single html file which contains multiple div.If yes then length of that single html file is going to be huge. Will it create any problem?

Comment: Your Index.html will be Huge but it will be efficient and fast... Try to make you code readable by adding comments... Everything else will be fine :)

Comment: Best of luck... And you know using this approach will help you in many ways.. For example localStorage doesn't work on BB OS 5 but if you are having a single file then you can use global variables instead... You will get to know slowly all the advantages :)

Comment: Here one issue is there if I press back button of my header then proper navigation take place, but when I press mobile back button then entire application exit

Comment: You need to register a backbutton listener and also capture the id of the page you are showing currently and then move along the pages accordingly.. Use `$.mobile.activePage.attr('id')`

Answer (score 0):

**try:**

```
window.location.href = "test.html";
```

**OR:**

```
window.location.assign("test.html");
```

[**SEE REFERENCE**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

Comment: Then try `window.location.assign("test.html");`

Comment: thank you for response. But window.location.assign("test.html");
 also not working

Comment: See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/sBV4d/1/ can you create a fiddle with your requirements.

Comment: How to add 2 seperate html files in fiddle. Because In my application I have two seperate html files. And from one html file I am calling another.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `window.location.replace("test.html")`;

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery mobile you can turn of ajax by setting some [initiation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html) variables. You need to load this script before you load jQuery mobile

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  //apply overrides here
  $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

With ajax turned off you can now still use your $.mobile.changePage().

Now to create a back button all you have to do is give the link an attribute of [data-rel="back"](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html)

```
<li><a href="#" data-theme="b" data-rel="back">Go Back</a></li>
```