# options to navigate from one page to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi I want to navigate from one page to another without ajax. With ajax we can use `$.mobile.changePage('test.html')` But I am targeting blackberry5+ version. Instead of `window.location` and `<a href="test.html">` is there is any other option available. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I answered in detail here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11663279/window-location-not-work-properly

Comment: @Coder_sLaY  Thanks for detail response. Let me check it I will be back. Once again Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try:

window.location.href = "test.html"; 
OR:

window.location.assign("test.html");
 window.location.replace("test.html");

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand but onclick="setLocation('newurl.html');" is another method?